# Filter based on other dataframe if any match

Tags: python, pandas

I have this DF with users and KPIs (1 present, 0 not)

```
global_df = pd.DataFrame({'Users':[1,2,3,4],
                     'KPI_1':[1,0,0,0],
                     'KPI_2':[1,1,0,0]})
```

It looks like:

```
     Users  KPI_1  KPI_2
0      1      1      1
1      2      0      1
2      3      0      0
3      4      0      0
```

Then I have a separate df, one row per filter, with the conditions (just showing one):

```
filter_condition = pd.DataFrame({'KPI_1':[1],
                             'KPI_2':[1]})
```

It looks like:

```
     KPI_1  KPI_2
0      1      1
```

This returns KeyError:

```
global_df[global_df[any(filter_condition)]]
```

Expected result (user 1 and 2 because they have KPI_1 or KPI_2 to 1):

```
     Users  KPI_1  KPI_2
0      1      1      1
1      2      0      1
```

**Note this is only the first row of the dataframe, I need to be able to iterate for every row in the filter_conditiosn dataframe where there can be N columns, for the sake of the example I just added two**

**EDIT**

This is close, but it removes usersId and adds a lot of nans:

```
global_df[global_df[filter_condition.columns]==1]

   Users  KPI_1  KPI_2
0    NaN    1.0    1.0
1    NaN    NaN    1.0
2    NaN    NaN    NaN
3    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: why is row 3 missed? oh your input doesn't match the dataframe you printed..

Comment: @Umar.H Sorry you are right, corrected

Comment: edit the row for USER 4 of input too, it contains `1` in the `KPI_2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the rows of `filter_condition`, then for each row, slice the portion of `global_df` having the common columns with `filtered_df` and compare it with the row values using `eq` and reduce using `any` along the columns axis to create a boolean mask

```
for i, r in filter_condition.iterrows():
    filtered_df = global_df[global_df[r.keys()].eq(r).any(1)]
    # TODO: Process the filtered dataframe
```

---

```
   Users  KPI_1  KPI_2
0      1      1      1
1      2      0      1
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, thinking if there is any way to avoid iteratring  and simply applying the filter directly.

Comment: @AlejandroA Might be possible. May be I misunderstood the question, Do you need to produce a **single output filtered df** by checking condition for every row in `filtered_condition` dataframe or for each row in `filtered_condition` dataframe we need to produce separate output df?

Comment: The first one you mention, the SQL equivalent would be something like SELECT * FROM global_df WHERE KPI_1==1 OR KPI_2 == 2.

For my real case it could be possible that I have n KPIs, so the query should be able to adapt if possible.

Comment: As you have mentioned in your question `I need to be able to iterate for every row in the filter_condition dataframe where there can be N columns,`, I guess you need separate result set for each row in `filtered_condition`? If not please edit your question and include one or two more rows in `filtered_condition` df and update your expected output accordingly.

Comment: I think this matches the requirement most closely

Answer (score 2):

we can use `reduce` from the functools lib to return a boolean to filter with.

we can also create a dictionary from your filter dataframe to filter each column by.

```
from functools import reduce 

d = filter_condition.stack().groupby(level=1).agg(list).to_dict()
#  {'KPI_1': [1], 'KPI_2': [1]}

global_df.loc[reduce(lambda a,b: a | b, [global_df[k].isin(v) for k,v in d.items()])]
```

---

```
   Users  KPI_1  KPI_2
0      1      1      1
1      2      0      1
```

Comment: that is a very good solution! out of curiosity what does the a,b a|b  does? A bit confusing and wondering if this would work if I had more KPIs (as mentioned in my issue)

Comment: @AlejandroA - I think re-shaping your dataframe and doing a merge would be better. In regards to your question I agree it's confusing and not very pythonic, I think `reduce` came from the functional programming world, `reduce`  applies a function to the first two items in an iterable (k,v here) it uses that to generate a result which is the boolean it then repeats that operation to get a single cumulative value. Honestly, it's a little complex and I don't understand it fully. I would read [here](https://realpython.com/python-reduce-function/) for more info. `a | b` means either conditionA or B

Answer (score 1):

Use `df.loc`. Just do a:

```
result = global_df.loc[(global_df['KPI_1'] == 1) | (global_df['KPI_2'] == 1)]
```

Comment: I need a more programatic way to do it for N defined number of columns, as there are plenty of filters that represent a row in a dataframe, no hardcoded name columns

Comment: Can you please describe a bit more about the filter df?

Comment: Hi, added a note and an extra row to the df filter, it just needs to be able to check. The filtering should not be harcoded, should be built based on a dataframe that has columns as conditions and it's values.

Comment: So in the filter_condition, there will be three entries for this condition? or just one? how do you know whether the filter condition is the OR of the columns or the AND of the columns?

Comment: Because this "Expected result (user 1 and 2 because they have KPI_1 or KPI_2 to 1)", it's an or condition, also in my code I tried to go for the any() approach, meaning that I expect if any value for the columns passed is 1 it should be selected.

Comment: So basically you're working on `OR`, right?

Comment: Yes, any if any 1 in row for the given conditions of the filter, I keep it

Answer (score 1):

Well, the error is explainable as you are trying to find a boolean index that is not present in your `global_df`.

```
indexes = set()
for column in filter_condition.columns:
    indexes = indexes.union(global_df[global_df[column].isin(filter_condition[column])].index)
global_df.loc[indexes]
```

I've used `isin` here as you've used a list in your `filter_conditon`, so I am hoping you're planning to use multiple values there.

This is one of the ways, you could choose, will update once I come up with some better approach. Also, since you're going to use columns to be the same somehow, it would be better to use Series rather than a Data frame.

EDIT: Global_df is fixed now in the question.

Another simple approach

```
condition = '|'.join(f'{column} in {filter_condition[column].values}' for column in filter_condition.columns)
global_df.query(condition)
```

This will basically perform the same function as above

```
global_df:
   Users  KPI_1  KPI_2
0      1      1      1
1      2      0      1
2      3      0      0
3      4      0      0


filter_condition:
    KPI_1  KPI_2
0      1      1


Output:
   Users  KPI_1  KPI_2
0      1      1      1
1      2      0      1
```